# Remove line from text file if it contains string java

Tags: java

I want to do read from text file, if I find certain email then I want to remove the entire line.

So I want to remove `email555@email.com`

```
stuffherestuffemail555@email.comstuffstuff
otherrandomwordsinrandomorder
reandom word and spaces maybe @ and charcters email555@email.com
APPLEPEARAPPLE
CATDOGCAT
CATDOGPEARemail555@email.comDogPear
```

To this

```
otherrandomwordsinrandomorder
APPLEPEARAPPLE
CATDOGCAT
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


class SendReq {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
IOException{

    File inputFile = new File("testfile.txt");
    if (!inputFile.exists()){
        inputFile.createNewFile();
    }
    File tempFile = new File("tempfile.txt");
    if (!tempFile.exists()){
        tempFile.createNewFile();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String lineToRemove = "NAMEOFEMAIL@EMAIL.com";
    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
        writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    System.out.println(successful);

  }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: OH GOD it took all my lines and mashed them together, sorry this is my first post.

Comment: If (trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) continue; ?